# How to get tablename from Event in Behavior

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm writing a behavior in CakePHP 3.0.11, and I can var_dump() and Log::debug() the $event object in my behavior's beforeSave() method, and can see the object data, but cannot access the object's properties.
I am simply trying to get the table (alias, className, tablename, anything) name from the object.
I would like to do something like this in my Behavior:

```
public function beforeSave(Event $event, Entity $entity)
{
    $table = $event->_alias;
    // etc.
}
```

I tried the event's subject() method which extracts the table object from the event,

```
$table = $event->subject();
```

When I var_dump or debug the object returned, it shows:

```
Debug: App\Model\Table\CompaniesTable Object
(
    [registryAlias] => Companies
    [table] => companies
    [alias] => Companies
    [entityClass] => App\Model\Entity\Company
    [associations] => Array
        (
            [0] => defaultshippingusers
    (...)
    [defaultConnection] => default
    [connectionName] => default
)
```

But I cannot access 'table', 'alias', etc. from my $table object.
When I do, I get a fatal error:

> Table Companies is not associated with 'alias'

Is there a simple way to get the Table name from the $event object in a behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dumping objects does not necessarily give you a representation of the objects structure, but custom formatted debug information, defined via [**the magic `__debugInfo()` method**](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo).

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.11/src/ORM/Table.php#L2190**

`Table` classes do not have `table` or `alias` properties, but methods with the same name, just have a look at the Cookbook and the API docs.

```
$alias = $event->subject()->alias();
```

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects > Basic Usage](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#basic-usage)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Table](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Table::alias()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_alias)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Table::table()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_table)**
- ...

Comment: Although the Cookbook actually doesn't reference the ->alias() method - you have to dig through the API reference.

Comment: @DJFar That's correct. The "_or_" in my answer is a typo, it should have been "_and_".

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the table name or alias directly from the behaviour without using the $event object:

```
$this->getTable()->table();
$this->getTable()->alias();
```

This is useful if you add your own functions to the behaviour which don't pass in the $event.